# Ad-invariant scalar product on complex vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, inner-products

Let's say we have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over a complex vector space, $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathfrak{g}$. What is the defining property for an ad-invariant real valued scalar product
\begin{equation}
\langle z_1,[z_2,z_3] \rangle = \langle [z_1,z_2^*],z_3 \rangle
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\langle z_1,[z_2,z_3] \rangle = \langle  [z_1,z_2],z_3 \rangle
\end{equation}

Comment: What is $z_2^*$?

Comment: The complex conjugate. For matrices we would need the complex conjugate transpose.

Comment: You did not mention that the elements of $\frak g$ are matrices. Anyway, that doesn't matter. The second option is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this mess with the complex structure. Assume $x$ is a complex number. Then $\langle z_1,[x \cdot z_2,z_3] \rangle=x \cdot \langle z_1,[ z_2,z_3] \rangle$ but $ \langle [z_1,x \cdot z_2],z_3 \rangle = x^* \cdot \langle [z_1, z_2],z_3 \rangle $. So they are not the same even though they should be due to ad invariance. The only way around this is to use the first definition I guess

Comment: I am sorry; I was thinking about $\bigl[z_1,[z_2,z_3]\bigr]=\bigl[[z_2,z_2],z_3\bigr]$, which has nothing to do with scalar products.

Comment: No problem. I think my calculation shows that the first one should be right. But I have never seen it anywhere written down

Comment: I don't see why it should be either of these. I don't have experience with the complex setting, but shouldn't ad-invariance just mean that the ad operators are Hermitian skew self-adjoint?

Comment: Conjugation is not part of a "complex structure", and rather defines a real form of a complex structure.

Comment: The inner product should be real. I edited the post

Comment: What should a real-valued scalar product on a complex vector space be? If it's not identically $0$, it cannot be complex-linear or complex-antilinear in either component, as e.g. $i$ times a non-zero real number is a non-real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the "correct" definition of invariance for a bilinear or hermitian form $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ on a vector space $V$ with respect to a Lie algebra representation $\rho: \mathfrak g \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is:

$$\langle \rho(x).v,w\rangle = -\langle v, \rho(x).w\rangle \qquad\text{ for all } x \in \mathfrak g, v,w \in V. \quad (*)$$

For $\rho=ad$ (and e.g. the Killing form) this is often written in the way $\langle [a,b],c\rangle = \langle a, [b,c]\rangle$ you allude to, which in that case is equivalent to the above via $x=-b, a=v, c=w$ and using $[r,s]=-[s,r]$. Still, the above should be preferred due to its much greater generality.

But also with that better definition, you will notice (analogously to your own comment), you run into a problem if $V$ is complex, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is hermitian (i.e. conjugate-linear in, say, the second components), and if you are allowed to multiply $\rho(x)$ through with complex scalars. Indeed, $(*)$ implies that for all scalars $a$ that you can multiply $x$ with and which commute with $\rho$:

$a\langle \rho(x).v,w\rangle = \langle a\rho(x).v,w\rangle = \langle \rho(ax).v,w\rangle \stackrel{(*)}= -\langle v, \rho(ax).w\rangle = -\langle v, a\rho(x).w\rangle =-\color{red}{\bar a}\langle v, \rho(x).w\rangle$

which divided by the original $(*)$ implies $a=\bar a$.

Now the way out is *not* to not allow complex $V$ or try to force the hermitian inner product to be "real valued" as in the comments, because that would force it to be identically $0$ (and hence not really a product).

Further, as regards your proposed first option, as several comments point out, there is no natural definition for something like $z^*$ in this setting if $\mathfrak g$ is a complex Lie algebra. Indeed, to define that, you would need to choose a *real structure* of that $\mathfrak g$. The proposed matrix trick also doesn't work in general: What if the conjugate transpose is not in the Lie algebra? (E.g. just take as $\mathfrak g$ some Lie algebra of upper triangular matrices.)

The actual way out is to realize (pun intended) that all this only works for **real** Lie algebras $\mathfrak g$, so that in the above, $a \in \mathbb R$. Actually, it should turn out later in the theory that such invariant inner products need a kind of compactness which only works for certain real Lie algebras, not complex ones. This way, the theory is treated in Bourbaki's *Lie Groups and Algebras*, chapter IX (Compact Lie Groups), which starts with a discussion of exactly this kind of invariant hermitian products.

Comment: Do you also know, if an Ad-invariant scalar product can exists on a complex Lie algebra. Where $\operatorname{Ad}:G\rightarrow GL(\mathfrak{g})$

Comment: Sorry, I have no access to the book. I mean if $G$ is i.e. $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and I want an invariant inner product on its Lie algebra, with respect to the representation of $GL$ on $\mathfrak{gl}$, i.e. $\langle \rho(g)v,\rho(g)w \rangle=\langle v,w \rangle$, $\rho: GL(n,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow GL(\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C}))$

Comment: If the inner product is hermitian, then that won't work for $n\ge 2$. Because otherwise $Ad(G)$ is contained in the unitary group $U(n^2)$, which is compact, so $Ad(G)$ is compact itself, but also a complex matrix group, hence (e.g. by Liouville) finite. I.e. $G$ needs to be finite modulo its abelian centre $Z(G)= ker(Ad)$.